# grpc-Python max_workers limiting number of simultaneous processes

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc, grpc-python

while using python grpc server,

`server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))`

this is general way in which grpc server is instantiated. But with this running, if I try to run more than 10 instances of client , which expects server streaming, the 11th one doesn't work (I am running 10 instances of client which connects to this server and gets the stream)

Even if I change max_workers to None, max it creates is 40 threads (8 cores x 5 as per documentation), so max 40 clients can be served simultaneously in that case.
Is this the expected behavior ?

I was working on my code, but tried with general grpc python code documented here:

https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html

I am able to reproduce the same issue with this.

To reproduce it, just run `route_guide_server.py` in one window with max_workers= 4 and then try to run 4-5 different clients in different windows . The 4th client will have to wait till one of the client is finished. (To get better view, add a time.sleep in yield)

If a large number of clients (100s and 1000s of clients) want to access grpc server in python with streaming (which should be continuous), then anymore clients will never get chance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the expected behavior.

After running my own test code, yes if you supply an argument of None to max_workers then 40 is the max.  However, if I set the max to 100 then sure enough I can have at most 100 concurrent workers.  This should be expected behavior because a thread pool is created based on the number of workers requested.  You cannot expect that if you don't supply a number of max workers that it will just scale up and down at run time.  Not without changing grpc and concurrent futures thread pool.  With the way the interface is coupled, in python grpc right now we must used concurrent futures threadpool, so we must supply an argument to max_workers if we want it to be more than 40, and it must be set at compile time.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your answer. Two things I want to ask in this regard:
1) is this the behaviour for python grpc only? as in other grpc implementations like go, I didn't see anything like this( there we don't need to specify no of threads). So, does that mean it automatically scales up in those grpc implementations?

2) If this is the case for python grpc, is there any way in which I can scale this for production? Let's say initially 100- 200 clients connect, but later on, suddenly if around 5000-7000 clients are created, then the application will fail correct?

Comment: Good questions.  I have unfortunately not used grpc for anything other than Python at this time.  If I get some time soon I could try doing something in go to test your question, but because go is so well focused on concurrency and goroutines use such little memory, it would not surprise me at all if go grpc does automatically scale.  Python threads use OS threads which are orders of magnitude more memory.  Scaling this up is very possible, but it could get complicated very quickly.  For example, you could use load balancing, where additional grpc server's are ready to spinup when....

Comment: detecting that all threads in the thread pool are in use.  grpc python does have reflection so I'm sure there are ways that you could either use grpc python to see how many threads are left, or track it yourself.  You could create a system that would launch new grpc servers on demand.  If your requirements allow it you could make it simpler and close all current connections, launch a new server with more threads.  For many applications this would be unacceptable.  In the python grpc road map they are planning to support asyncio which might make this problem moot.